# ReactJs not load sass files

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, node-sass

I have Reactjs app it was working fine, I have change my pc and get the code from repository after I run `npm install` all the packages downloaded find, when I run my app `npm start` the app is running fine but the SASS not complied and the application runs without any CSS files (all classes the browser cannot found), I tried a lot of solutions by installing SASS globally or trying `npm eject` by changing the `webconfig.dev.js` file with no luck, or but `node-sass` in `devDependencies` it is not working.

I am rely stuck for 2 days.

I will share my `package.json` file below :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "homepage": ".",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "4.0.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "4.0.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.11",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.12",
    "@spekta/react-oidc": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.17",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chart.js": "2.7.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "0.0.0-bb1c82155",
    "jquery": "^3.7.0",
    "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "jquery.fancytree": "^2.38.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "money": "^0.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "oidc-react": "^1.5.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primereact": "^9.2.3",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-file-viewer": "^1.2.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.4",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.4.5",
    "react-number-format": "^4.9.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.9",
    "react-router": "^6.15.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-spinners": "^0.11.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "to-words": "^3.6.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.22.10"
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please share the code where you import your styles.

Comment: this is the code in app.js (main):<code>import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import './App.scss';
const App = () => {
}